# import Tkinter fails with python 2.7.3 Mac OSX 10.8.2

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have read extensively on this problem, but not found a usable solution.  Many of them suggest rebuilding python from scratch.  That's a hurdle I'd like to avoid, if possible.  So I am going to give this question one last, desperate shot.  It shouldn't be a duplicate of the many similar questions on stackoverflow because I believe it to be specific to my installation, even though the symptoms are similar to others.

Here is the current state of my installation.  I've installed lots of other packages like `numpy` and `matplotlib` without problems, but this one is stumping me.

```
MacBookPro:lib-tk rebcabin$ arch -x86_64 /opt/local/bin/python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Nov 17 2012, 19:54:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', ... 
'/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
...]
```

Notice `lib-tk` on the path.  Let's go look at `lib-tk`:

```
MacBookPro:lib-tk rebcabin$ ls -la
total 3704
...
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  155634 Nov 17 19:55 Tkinter.py
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  224887 Nov 17 19:55 Tkinter.pyc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  224887 Nov 17 19:55 Tkinter.pyo
...
```

Let's try to import it

```
>>> import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

Most of the reading I've done on this topic comes from just pasting the error above into Google.  Some of the suggestions are quite glib and useless: "just reconfigure your python in setup.py, type 'make' and your problem is solved."  Which setup.py?  There are dozens in my python directories. Which makefile?  Ditto. Maybe the context is that of building python from scratch, which, again, I will avoid because I don't want to risk breaking all the other packages that work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the path, It seems like you probably installed python via macports.  If that's the case, look for something like [`py-tkinter`](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=Tkinter) -- e.g.

```
sudo port install py27-tkinter
```